# Making a number whole incase of float

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Possibility to avoid 0 after decimal if the answer is a whole number?
For example:

```
void Start(){
  float a = 12.2f;
  float b = 2.8f;
  float answer = a + b;
  string answerText = answer.ToString("F1"); //Answer is 15.0
}
```

Now I will get the answer text as 15.0, but I want to avoid this and make it a whole number text like 15. This should happen only if there is 0 after the decimal place. How do I do this?

Comment: A number has no format until it is converted to a string. Until then 15.0 and 15 are identical.

Comment: Use `answer.ToString("0.##########")` whenever you want to display number in the UI.

Comment: Sorry I will improve the question and ask

Comment: You could do `Math.Floor(answer) == answer` but you would need to use either `double` or `decimal` type (You would have to use `Math.Ceil` for negative numbers though.

Comment: @phuzi I have improved my question now.

Comment: The comment by @Chetan would satisfy your requirements and conditionally display the decimal point and any decimal places only if there are any.

Comment: Why the `15.0` edge case anyway?  Why not just cast `answer` to an `int`?

Answer (score -1):

That ".0" part of the number is only going to be important if you output that value as a string somewhere. In this case, you can use something like `string.Format(value, "F0")` to avoid outputting the fractional part.

If you are simply doing calculations on values then this usually doesn't matter since 15 and 15.0 are essentially the same thing (the usual caveat about IEEE floating-point format applies since that 15.0 may actually be something like 15.00000000156).